# Facebook OpenGraph meta tags unread

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

My client updated me that Facebook sharing didn't work anymore on his website i made. I've been looking and testing many things and it seems that Facebook doesn't read those metas properly and triggers errors in the debugger. I've tried and read many times documentation, changed the attributes.

The website : http://www.celianemoller.fr
Facebook debugger : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=www.celianemoller.fr

The Facebook **scraper** debug returns an empty response, which is confusing.

Maybe you guys can see what i can't. Any input on this subject can be really helpful.

Comment: I tried several “DNS Checker” services for `www.celianemoller.fr`, and most of them reported some kind of problem (“Delegation not found at parent. No delegation could be found at the parent, making the zone unreachable from the Internet.”) - so I’d look into that. If Facebook can not even resolve the domain name, then of course they can’t read any meta data either.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CBroe i'll take a look at this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick update : I had those DNS problems and resolved, but still problems getting meta datas from Facebook.

So i browsed here on stackoverflow on other answers made by @CBroe and i found that Facebook had problems with GZIP content encoded.

For those who encounter the same problems, here's an Apache Rule to handle this : 
`<IfModule mod_setenvif.c> 
    BrowserMatch facebookexternalhit no-gzip 
</IfModule>`

And i get the meta datas updated on Facebook debugger !